# How to cast a CodeDOM object into its correct type

Tags: c#, codedom

I have some code that generates an array of tuples of CodeCompileUnit and CodeTypeDeclarations of different classes.
After I generate the array I want to be able to invoke and create an instance of a given member of the array.  However, can't seem to figure out how to get the name and type of the class defined in CodeTypeDeclaration.

```
var tuple = Factory.CreateTuple(...);

var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var parameters = new CompilerParameters
                    {
                        GenerateInMemory = true,
                        IncludeDebugInformation = true
                    };
var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, tuple.GetCodeCompileUnit());
var runtimeObj = (????tuple.GetCodeTypeDeclaration().GetType()???)Activate.CreateInstance(results.CompileAssembly.GetType(tuple.GetCodeTypeDeclaration().Name));
runtimeObj.DoStuff();
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: BTW, your question doesn't match your code. You already figured how to get the type using `Assembly.GetType()`.

Comment: Thanks, changed it to closer reflect the question.

Comment: Btw, svick note that I still doesn't know how to get the type.  .GetType() here returns the type of CodeTypeDeclaration, not the type of the class contained in the declaration.

Comment: I meant `results.CompileAssembly.GetType(…)`, not `codeTypeDeclaration.GetType()`. The latter will of course return `typeof(CodeTypeDeclaration)`.

Comment: So there is no way to get the type directly from the CodeTypeDeclaration... I see.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can cast to a dynamically created type.

I see two options here:

1. Make your generated type implement a non-generated interface and cast to that:

   ```
   var runtimeObj = (ICanDoStuff)Activate.CreateInstance(…);
   runtimeObj.DoStuff();
   ```
2. Use `dynamic` or reflection to invoke the method:

   ```
   dynamic runtimeObj = Activate.CreateInstance(…);
   runtimeObj.DoStuff();
   ```

Comment: Thanks. 1. doesn't really work for my case, but will just have to dynamically invoke.